# Old style ASCII input without Ctrl

Tags: front-end, notebooks, compatibility, input-forms

This is an example from an old book: "The Mma book 5th ed". It was called "Entering 2D input". If I paste the following in a notebook:

```
\!\( \[Sum] \+ \( n = 0 \) \% m 1 \/ f[n] \)
```

it promptly gives me a formatted expression but I can't enter the same text in an input cell on my own. It is curiosity more than anything but could someone please point out what I am doing wrong?

[image]

Comment: Esc-sum-esc  gives the $\Sigma$.  "sum" is 3 lowercase letters.  Ctrl-underscore puts you in subscript mode.  n=0  is the index initializer.  Ctrl=%  goes from subscript to superscript.  5  is the upper limit.  Ctrl-spacebar  goes from superscript to plain input.  1/f[n] is the summand, followed by shift-enter to evaluate the expression.

Comment: @LouisB : I know the shortcuts with CTRL. I can't enter this legacy expression (shown with an error above) in an input cell, although I can paste it as seen in `In[1]`. The notebook cell is okay with the paste but somehow does not accept it character by character. I was wondering why. Thanks for your kind response.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The functionality still exists in current version of *Mathematica*, but it has slightly changed for several times in past versions.

According to my test, the functionality is introduced in *v3*, but auto conversion doesn't happen in any version if one directly types the expression inside the notebook. In *v3* and *v4*, one needs to manually convert the cell to `StandardForm` by e.g. pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>n</kbd> as the last step:

[image]

In *v5*, one more extra step is required. One needs to first create a cell and convert the cell to `InputForm` by e.g. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>i</kbd>, then enter the code and convert the cell back to `StandardForm`.

Start from *v6*, raw `InputForm` is introduced, and one needs to create a cell and convert the cell to **raw** `InputForm` by e.g. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>r</kbd>, then enter the code and convert the cell back to `StandardForm`. This remains to be the behavior of *v12*:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for this informative answer. May I ask what your screen capture tool is called?

Comment: @Syed I'm using LICEcap: https://www.cockos.com/licecap/ Some other tools are discussed here: https://mathematica.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1058/1871 BTW for recording keystroke I'm using KeyCastow:  https://www.ugmfree.it/Forum/messages.aspx?TopicID=513